# CentOS server: how to detect network status changes

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have setup a CentOS 6.4 server (minimal install) which is connected to network through an ethernet cable. The problem is that when the network link goes down, the status changes are not automatically detected but if i type "ifconfig" the interface still keeps its IP address (which is assigned by a DHCP server). After some time that the link is down the interface loses the address but when the link comes up again the network connection is not automatically restored like it would happen in a desktop computer. Even the command "dhclient eth0" does not always work to restore things, and I have to restart the whole network service with "/ect/init.d/network restart".

Is there any way to automatically detect network status changes like it happens in desktop installations? I'm thinking about a cron script that every 5 minutes pings a server outside my network and if it doesn't get any response it restarts network service, but this does not sound very efficient... is there another way?

EDIT: I realized I have not explained the situation correctly. My network topology is: server --> switch --> router --> external network (the router is another centos server with DHCPD).
For some reasons (that i'm not getting), when it happens that the router goes down and reboots, the other server becomes unreachable, and I have to manually restart network service on it. So the link does not effectively go down (the switch keeps it up), but the status change is at IP level.

Comment: I don't really see another approach besides the one you stated, but I don't think this approach is that inefficient since the res sources required to ping are minimal

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you have NetworkManager enabled, I usually don't use it in the servers but it can help you in this case because it will monitor automatically the connections (it is quite common in desktop installations).

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-NetworkManager.html

To look for messages indicating an issue with the NIC just check the kernel ring buffer using the dmesg command.

For example when the cable is disconnected from a given interface this is what I get:

```
igb: eth1 NIC Link is Down
```

The first word will depend on the name of your network driver.

You could also configure the system to log these messages also to /var/log/messages (by default I am not sure if they appear there). Then it would be just a matter of monitoring the log, look for similar messages and restart the network service.

In any case the NetworkManager, if it is not already enabled, it should be an easier solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I commented in the other reply I realized I have not explained the situation correctly, so I have edited my original post. Network Manager solution works like a charm only if the link does effectively go down, but not if only the router does. I have realized that even if I connect my laptop to the switch does not detect any change. I'm beginning to think that my original "ping" idea could be the only way to go...

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called miimon for monitoring the network interface's status. `ethtool` will give you the link status.

```
$ethtool eth0
    ...
    Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but realized I have not explained the situation correctly, so I have edited my original post. This solution unfortunately is not applicable in my case because there is a switch between server and router that keeps the link up even if the router goes down, so I always read "yes".